# Simple Trignometric Equation

Tags: trigonometry

If $ N $ is some positive integer and $ \alpha $ some real number, how do I solve
$$
\frac{\sin( x (N+1) )}{\sin(x N )} = \alpha
$$
for x? Or is there no simple closed form expression for x?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

$\sin(nx)$ and $\cos(nx)$ are always n-th order [polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Double-angle.2C_triple-angle.2C_and_half-angle_formulae) in $\sin x$ and/or $\cos x$, so there's that, but, then again, not even polynomials can be solved analytically for $n>4.$